# Disable mangling in babel-minify

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I want to turn off mangling in the babel minify preset with webpack 4.

**What I did:** I configure `babel-minify-preset` straight in the webpack config file using `mangle: false` as described in the presets's documentation https://github.com/babel/minify/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-minify#options

**Symptom:** the file is minimized, but the names are still mangled.

I know my `babel-minify-preset` options are not ignored because when I set `builtIns` to `false` I get this error: https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/904

Bellow is the relevant part of my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  target: "electron-main",
  [...]
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          /** executed from last to first */
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [ "minify", { mangle: false, builtIns: false } ]
              ]
            }
          },
          { loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
  },
  [...]
  optimization: { minimize: true }
};
```

I'm using

- webpack 4.25.1
- @babel/core 7.1.6
- babel-preset-minify 0.5.0